# Backbone.js web application is unusable on Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, backbone.js

I have developed my web application w/o testing it on IE. Though it worked fine on all the browsers viz. Chrome, Firefox, Safari but when it comes to IE there is a strange behavior.

Sometimes the app loads and some times a blank page is loaded as if none of the "bind" events had any effect.

And the lucky times when the app loads, the nav panel is partially missing. I can't show you the code right now coz I am not sure what part to show and where I am doing it wrong.

If anyone of you can provide me a checklist of what to check and what tools would be ideal for debugging on IE then it would be great.

And if anyone of you can tell me most common backbone.js bugs on IE then that too would help.

PS: Version of IE I am testing with: IE8

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Some issues in IE are:

Trailing commas on Objects:

E.g.

```
 App.model = Backbone.Model.extend({
   url: "/foo/bar",

   validate: function() {
   },
 });
```

Should be:

```
 App.model = Backbone.Model.extend({
   url: "/foo/bar",

   validate: function() {
   }
 });
```

The use of functions that are not available in IE such as `lastIndexOf()`

A third thing to check for is invalid HTML.  IE can be particularly picky about your HTML structure.  Be sure that all open tags either have a matching close tag, or are self closing with `/>`

If you are using JSON methods such as `JSON.parse()` and `JSON.stringify()` then be sure to include a JSON library such as [JSON2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js).

Comment: +1 Trailing commas and JSON are the big ones, another I've ran into is the `trim` function on Strings

Comment: I use coffeescript so no issues with trailing commas, for me it was closing tag `/>`, but fixed :)

Comment: Another one is the usage of html5 shiv in case the project is in html5.

Comment: Another issue I faced was stray closing div inside template (handlebar). All browsers it works fine but In IE8. I lost about a day to find it out. careful!!

Comment: Same for me, a stray closing div in a haml-generated template (an if/else statement didn't line up)

Answer (score 3):

If you are running Windows 7, you should upgrade to IE9. Then you can use IE developer tools to debug your page. It is similar to using firebug or the webkit developer tools. With the IE developer tools, you can emulate back to IE7 as well.

If you are running XP, you should get Windows 7 and then upgrade to IE9.

Also, you should use something like [es5 shims](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim). This provides javascript functionality that is present in modern browsers, but not old versions of IE.

Comment: This is pretty late for a comment but IE9/10 emulation of IE7 is *not* the same as actually running IE7 on XP. You will get different results.

Comment: I'll second that. I've seen real life IE8 do different things to the IE11 "IE8 mode".

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic Binding is not supported by MSIE <10 ,but its working out in MSIE 10.
The jQuery codes like .show(),.hide() might work in static binding ,but in case of Backbone ,Node like frame work using dynamic binding,templating and other technology might not work on it
MSIE 10 will be able to catch on it

Answer (score 0):

I have found that your HTML templates need to be well formed HTML. Chrome and Firefox seem much more forgiving but with IE 8, the inclusion of a bad  caused a blank view to be displayed.